# Why on a community wiki question some answers are community wiki and some are not?

Tags: support

Example: [Introductory Group theory textbook](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/introductory-group-theory-textbook)

I'm miffed by this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question [was merged](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/25506/revisions) with [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311961/group-theory-for-beginners) after it was made community wiki. The answers from the merge source were not automatically converted to CW upon the merge, it seems.

Answer (score 7):

Leaving the specific question aside:

The phenomenon of non-CW or "mixed" answers to CW questions  used to be quite common when CW could still be induced by OP (or by edits) of question posts.

When they did this after some answers where given, then the existing answers were not made CW.